# Open a new window and navigate the old window on button click

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a website with a button that opens up a pop-up window with information. When this button is clicked I want the window with the button to navigate to a new window. Hopefully using the Url.Action commands. The following code was my attempt but does not work. The second part <%=Url.Action("MainScreenAction", "Controller")%> is what should navigate the main screen. But it stopped everything from working.

```
<input type="button" value="test" onclick="openwindow('<%=Url.Action("PopupWindowAction", "Controller")%>');<%=Url.Action("MainScreenAction", "Controller")%>"/>
```

Openwindow() is a javascript function that just allows me to open the passed href (url.action) to open it in a pop-up window.

Edit: I forgot to mention that this is in asp.net MVC

Comment: Are you talking about some version of asp.net-MVC?

Comment: Yes I'm sorry I should have mentioned that. I will edit that into the main description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the window's location

```
<input type="button" value="test" 
       onclick="openwindow('<%=Url.Action("PopupWindowAction", "Controller")%>');window.location='<%=Url.Action("MainScreenAction", "Controller")%>';"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the window.location.href for that. try below code:

```
  function reloadWindow(url)
    {
    window.location.href = url;
    }


<input type="button" value="test" 
       onclick="openwindow('<%=Url.Action("PopupWindowAction", "Controller")%>');reloadWindow('<%=Url.Action("MainScreenAction", "Controller")%>');"/>
```